# Defining alias for Tomcat Context inside web application

Tags: java, tomcat, alias, context.xml

I have set up a Tomcat 8.0 with two Hosts:

```
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>

  <Host name="sub1.mydomain.com"  appBase="sub1"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
  </Host>

  <Host name="sub2.mydomain.com"  appBase="sub2"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
  </Host>
```

The application deployed to `sub1` has a `META-INF/context.xml` with the following setting:

```
<Context path="/" aliases="/upload=/home/myuser/somepath"></Context>
```

where `/upload` is used inside the webapp as a virtual path to save uploaded files. When the application is started this warning is shown:

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context}     
Setting property 'aliases' to '/upload=/home/myuser/somepath' did not find a matching property
```

and when I save a file in `/upload` in the application it is simply saved in `upload` directory inside the deployed application (instead of being saved in `/home/myuser/somepath`). This setting used to work when there were not two `Host`s. Is is a bug or this feature does not work in this configuration or it is some misconfiguration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll note from the error message and from Tomcat 8 documentation [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes), that the `aliases` property no longer exists.

Refer to [The Migration Guide](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html) to fix it (and possible other problems).

Comment: Great thanks! This link also helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909329/after-migrating-to-tomcat-8-aliases-doesnt-work-any-more